# Error in the shuffle code for shuffle game of numbers

Tags: c#

```
if (same)
{
    MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore("You have finished the game in " + Hits.ToString() + " hits", "End of Game", 2);
}
```

There is an error at `MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore` - it shows non-invocable member `MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore` cannot be used like a method.

What should I do to solve this problem???

Comment: You are trying to 'call' an enumeration. Message boxes aren't shown like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBoxButtons` is an enumeration. The error occurs because you're attempting to incorrectly invoke its `AbortRetryIgnore` value as a method, which is not possible. You need to use [`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
MessageBox.Show(
    "You have finished the game in " + Hits.ToString() + " hits",
    "End of Game",
    MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore);
```

Comment: hey sorry to say but u missed  "s" at messageboxbutton whcih is showing error but thanx for the answer

Comment: `MessageBoxButton` is WPF, which I assumed you were using as the question wasn't tagged with `winforms`. Should have noticed the 's'. Rectified for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBoxButtons` is an enumeration, so its members cannot be called like methods.

You are looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload of `MessageBox.Show`. The code would look like:

```
MessageBox.Show("You have finished the game in " + Hits.ToString() + " hits", "End of Game", "End of Game!", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore);
```

Note that you would typically use `String.Format` instead of string concatenation for something like this.